# How to animate image in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

In my app i have shaking option which i implemented. In that activity i have bottle image which needs to animated like shaking the bottle. I am not aware of the animation in android and searched in google but couldn't find the exact one. I am just looking for an example.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these threads:

[shaking / wobble view animation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448732/shaking-wobble-view-animation-in-android)

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/shake-animation-example/

Also check the "Shake Image" section of:

http://jongladwin.blogspot.in/2010/03/androibasic-animation-samples.html