# How can I make vibrate animation for ImageView

Tags: android, animation, vibration

I have no idea for this animation.

How can I do it via XML like that? Or another solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" 
    android:fillAfter="true"> 
    ......
</set>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: check this answer: This worked great for  me  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9449590/607968

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This code shakes a view in horizontal direction

> shake.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_5"
    android:toXDelta="10" />
```

> cycle_5.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:cycles="5" />
```

> Method to shake ImageView

```
public void onShakeImage() {    
   Animation shake;
   shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);

   ImageView image;
   image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

   image.startAnimation(shake); // starts animation
}
```

Comment: setAnimation does not start it.
You need to use the startAnimation(shake) to actually start the animation.

Answer (score 10):

1) vibrate or
2) shake
(using property animation)the following code working for me.

```
 ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animateView, "rotation", 0f, 20f, 0f, -20f, 0f); // rotate o degree then 20 degree and so on for one loop of rotation.
// animateView (View object) 
        rotate.setRepeatCount(20); // repeat the loop 20 times
        rotate.setDuration(100); // animation play time 100 ms 
        rotate.start();
```

Comment: my savior @GeetThakur... hehe short and nice!

Answer (score 6):

Create **shake.xml** inside anim directory

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:duration="70"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="0" />
<translate
    android:duration="70"
    android:fromXDelta="40"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXDelta="-40" />
```

inside your java file add below method

```
public void animateView(View view){
    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.shake);
    view.startAnimation(shake);
}
```

and pass your view inside method for animation

```
animateView(yourView);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create animation file in anim directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromDegrees="-10"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="10" />



Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
your_view.startAnimation(shake);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me smoothly as i Expected

```
private void Shake(View view)
{
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(-5, 5,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(250);
    rotate.setStartOffset(50);
    rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(5));
    view.startAnimation(rotate);
}
```

Comment: Your solution matches my requirement for shaking to open rewards. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did create the **BUZZ** like animation for imageView. Here I also have added delay to make it really like **Buzzy effect**

1. In your Activity:

Here, `animShake` is `android.view.animation`

```
    animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake)
    imageView.startAnimation(animShake)
```

Don't forget to add `AnimationListener` for little delay of BUZZ effect

```
animShake.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {

        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            Handler().postDelayed({
                imageView.startAnimation(animShake)
            }, 1000)

        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {

        }
    })
```

2. anim `shake` XML file having only `translate`:

   ```
    android:duration="75"
    android:fromXDelta="-18%"
    android:repeatCount="11"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXDelta="18%" />
   ```