# GridView item magically appears under first item after item is removed and notifyDataSetChanged() called

Tags: android, animation, gridview

I have a GridView in which, inside its adapter, I have the following code inside the getView method:

```
if(deleteState){

    Animation deleteAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ThisApplication.getContext(), R.anim.delete_animation);
    holder.root.startAnimation(deleteAnimation);

}else{  
    holder.root.clearAnimation();
}
```

The R.anim.delete_animation is an iOS like animation that shakes the items:

```
<!-- Based on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9449590/1369016 -->
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromDegrees="-4"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="4" />
```

All good so far. The problem comes when I delete an item from the list. After I delete the item from my list in my adapter, I call notifyDataSetChanged(), just like below:

```
public void deletePhotoFromAdapter(final int position){

    listOfPhotos.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When I do that, the item gets deleted but, somehow, the view of the item I deleted **goes under the first item view of the GridView** itself! It's like the animation keeps the view alive (but somehow "transport" that view to be bellow the first item of the GridView). I am attaching three screenshots so you can see what I mean:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have also tried to stop the animation just before deleting the view itself. Then, another interesting thing happens. All the views have their animation stopped, but the one below the first item still appears (and it is still animated also!).

I have no idea where that view can be coming from. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Not a single answer? :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to delete it without the animation? I don't think the animation is the problem. Try to reload the adapter to the View after deleting the object. Just call

```
gridView.invalidateViews();
photosAdapter = new PhotosAdapter(this,
            R.layout.grid_item, listOfPhotos);
gridView.setAdapter(photosAdapterAdapter);
```

Give it a try. Greez

Comment: Thank you for replying Hans. Yes, I have tried to delete it without animation. Without the animation, everything works perfectly (and it is how I left the app in the end), but I really would like to add the animation. I have not tried to reset the adapter and invalidate the gridview manually though. Will try that next week and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I've just test it, but it did not work either. This bug is driving me crazy! :(