# Android buttonimage shake animation

Tags: java, android, xml, imagebutton, shake

I am new with android and im looking for a way to shake my buttonimage on click. I got this so far but it crashes all the time. Or if you click it nothing works.
I hope you people can help me out. if i forgot anythiing just say it. code can be messy.

i got a anim folder. with shakeanim.xml

code:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:src="@drawable/chest"
        android:background="@null"/>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton1"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
         android:text="100 Clicks" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.egghatcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton imageButton;

    TextView clicksToGo;

    Animation shake;

    private int clicks = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shakeanim);
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        clicksToGo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicks--;               
                clicksToGo.setText("You need to click " + clicks + " more times to open it");
                findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).startAnimation(shake);  
            } 
        });

    }


}
```

shakeanim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"

    android:toXDelta="10" />
```

Comment: if you really want it to shake you should use custom interpolaror that goes back and forth

Comment: Unfortunately you can’t use the interpolator in your XML resource of the animation and it is only available programmatically.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448732/shaking-wobble-view-animation-in-android

Answer (score 19):

Replace your shakeanim.xml file with this.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:duration="150"
        android:fromXDelta="-10%"
        android:repeatCount="5"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toXDelta="10%"/>
</set>
```

btw you can change your MainActivity "setOnClickListener" like this as you have already declared imageButton.

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicks--;               
                clicksToGo.setText("You need to click " + clicks + " more times to open it");
                imageButton.startAnimation(shake);  
            }  
        });
```

If this helps please mark it as the right answer. Thank you

Comment: the animation jumps!

Comment: what's with this formXDelta

Comment: android:duration="50" looks way less choppy in my opinion, and looks much better