# vibrate image in imageview

Tags: android, animation, imageview, vibration

I need to vibrete image in imageview

For that i used

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="70"
        android:fromDegrees="-5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="5"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toDegrees="5" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-10"
        android:toXDelta="10"
        android:repeatCount="5"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="70" />
</set>
```

implemented like

```
   Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.testanimation);
                        findViewById(R.id.imgview).startAnimation(shake);
```

working properly.. But i want to shake image on imageview touch down and stop shaking when user touch up imageview

```
imgview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  System.out.println(event.getAction());
  switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
         //WANT VIBRATEING/SHAKEING IMAGE
         break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         //WANT TO STOP VIBRATEING/SHAKING IMAGE
         break;
   }
   break;
  }
```

How to make it possible?
Thanks,
Pragna

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="100"
android:fromDegrees="-5"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:toDegrees="5" />
```

[shaking / wobble view animation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448732/shaking-wobble-view-animation-in-android)