# How to animate current Activity (not transition)?

Tags: android, android-animation

I wonder how to animate current Activity, not transition between activities. For example, I want to shift the activity slightly to the left and then move it back, so that it looks like a little shake effect. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried animating the view with id `android.R.id.content`?

Comment: why you trying to animate activity, you can animate a parent layout in your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found a solution:

```
    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.05f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(100);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    View viewActivity = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    if (viewActivity != null)
        viewActivity.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create animation instance like below

```
 Animation startAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.shaking_animation);
```

then u need to start that animation with your parent layout

```
   parent_layout.startAnimation(startAnimation);
```

you can get shake animation here [shaking / wobble view animation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448732/shaking-wobble-view-animation-in-android)

finally you can clear animation like below

```
parent_layout.clearAnimation();
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to get access to the root layout of the activity and then do some animations on it, e.g. if you use DataBindung it is just like this (but not the best idea for the kind of animation you want):

```
    binding.getRoot().animate().rotation(-5).setDuration(500).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            binding.getRoot().animate().rotation(5).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    binding.getRoot().animate().rotation(0).setDuration(500);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```